# How to extract create daily first boarding record in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata

I have a dataframe like this, which contains passenger id, date, and their origin location.

```
ID  DATE        Origin 
1   01/01/2012  A
1   01/01/2012  B
1   01/01/2012  C
1   01/02/2012  A
1   01/02/2012  B
1   01/02/2012  C
1   01/03/2012  A
1   01/03/2012  B
1   01/08/2012  A
2   01/01/2012  D
2   01/01/2012  C
2   01/01/2012  B
2   01/04/2012  D
2   01/04/2012  C
2   01/06/2012  D
3   01/03/2012  F
3   01/03/2012  G
3   01/09/2012  F
3   01/09/2012  G
```

I want to creat 'daily first boarding record' by using the datafram shown above

```
ID DATE        Origin
    1   01/01/2012  A
    1   01/02/2012  A
    1   01/03/2012  A
    1   01/08/2012  A
    2   01/01/2012  D
    2   01/04/2012  D
    2   01/06/2012  D
    3   01/03/2012  F
    3   01/09/2012  F
```

Group by ID and DATE, taking the first value for Origin in each group.

currently, I'm now using this code

```
Daily_First_record = aggregate(ORIGIN ~ ID + DATE, data=df, FUN='[', i=1)
```

however, this code is running slowly because my original dataset is quite large (about 1Gb csv). Is there any easy way to conduct the same job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID, DATE) %>%
    summarise(Origin = first(Origin))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) should be quite fast:

```
> dat[, .SD[1], by = c("ID", "DATE")]
   ID       DATE Origin
1:  1 01/01/2012      A
2:  1 01/02/2012      A
3:  1 01/03/2012      A
4:  1 01/08/2012      A
5:  2 01/01/2012      D
6:  2 01/04/2012      D
7:  2 01/06/2012      D
8:  3 01/03/2012      F
9:  3 01/09/2012      F
```

Where

```
dat <- fread("ID  DATE        Origin 
             1   01/01/2012  A
             1   01/01/2012  B
             1   01/01/2012  C
             1   01/02/2012  A
             1   01/02/2012  B
             1   01/02/2012  C
             1   01/03/2012  A
             1   01/03/2012  B
             1   01/08/2012  A
             2   01/01/2012  D
             2   01/01/2012  C
             2   01/01/2012  B
             2   01/04/2012  D
             2   01/04/2012  C
             2   01/06/2012  D
             3   01/03/2012  F
             3   01/03/2012  G
             3   01/09/2012  F
             3   01/09/2012  G")
```